# How to convert octet to QString?

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, qtcore, data-distribution-service

I have a octet in my sources. So I need to convert it to QString.

I tried  QString str(a); but it does not work. from what i read octet suppose to be a unsigned char

```
   a = 'A';
```

Update:
a is the octet, from what i read it says "Since a DDS_Octet is equivalent to 1 Byte (8bits)" (http://community.rti.com/kb/what-max-number-octets-i-can-put-topicdata-builtin-topics)

Update 2:

its defined as a unsigned char (unsigned byte)

Comment: What do you mean by "octet"? A single byte? What is `a`? How is it declared/defined?

Comment: Did you found the QString class in the .h file? What constructor overloads are available? What assignment operator overloads are available? There should be something with an array of char.

Comment: a is the octet, from what i read it says "Since a DDS_Octet is equivalent to 1 Byte (8bits)" (http://community.rti.com/kb/what-max-number-octets-i-can-put-topicdata-builtin-topics)

Comment: Please update your question instead of spreading the question in comments. -- Most readers understand that an octect is something like a BYTE, or a 8-bit-value, or a unsigned-char. But your compiler expects a C data type. Therefore please answer Joachims question.

Comment: An "octet" (8 bits) is something you transmit over a network. It only exists in a communication channel. In your computer you have bytes (each may or may not hold 8 bits), and C++ has `char` (always one byte). Just a terminology thing but important to get right.

Comment: "`I tried QString str(a); but it does not work.`" How does it not work? How about `QString str(QChar(a))`?

Comment: Please select an answer if the issue is resolved, otherwise let us know what is missing!

Answer (score 2):

Convert `unsigned char` to `QString`:

```
unsigned char a = 'A';
QString str = QString((QChar)a);
```

Comment: Not downvoting as I appreciate the willingness to help but.. First, this is C style casting with a class target (!), which is not necessarily guaranteed to work anytime. Secondly, even if it was a constructor call, that can be implicit, so there is little to no point in being explicit. Try out my previously pasted code if you do not believe my logic. :-) Additionally, it is bad to encourage char to QString conversion on its own in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should *not* convert an octet to a `QString` on its own. That will yield some superfluous conversion. What you would be better doing is probably convert it to `Q(Latin1)Char` and use that if you need to put some string manipulation together.

Just doing it on its own looks impractical. Should you still insist on this, use the QString constructor as follows:

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>

int main()
{
    unsigned char a = 'A';
    QString string(a);
    qDebug() << string;
    return 0;
}
```

#### main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = main
QT = core
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

#### Build and Run

```
qmake && make && ./main
```

#### Output

```
"A"
```

Let me not start my rant about QString requiring a QCoreApplication instance to work properly, so please let us forget about that for a second. :-)

This will work out-of-the-box since QString has a [constructor that takes QChar](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstring.html#QString-3) and that can be implicitly used since QChar has a [constructor that takes an unsigned char](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qchar.html#QChar-10).

By the way, octet is almost exclusively 8 bits per byte these days. I would not worry about it being handled differently, otherwise many software pieces could break underneath. Just see the code from the code that you linked, will you?

```
// DDS_Octet is defined to be 8 bits. If chars are not 8 bits
// on your system, this will not work.
```